# Clang user documentation

Tags: c, gcc, clang, clang-static-analyzer

*I was unsure whether to ask here or in superuser, but this site seemed more appropriate*

I'm looking for documentation/analysis on Clang specifically for these two areas:

- comparison of warnings provided by Clang vs. GCC

  - I'm specifically looking for the amount of checking that Clang is doing in comparison to GCC http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html
- description of the `--analyze` flag, what exactly does it check?

Comment: Actually, have you tried CLang Dev mailing list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did ask on the Clang mailing list and the documentation is non-existent at this point.

You can follow this thread for more information: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2011-March/013655.html